# adding markers to the map

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I would like to add a marker to the map using the form. Can anyone help me? Installing the map works. I want to display markers after entering x and y, and read this data from the table. I have 2 inputs, one for X and the other for Y after clicking "add" I add this data to the table and I have 2 objects, etc ... but only one marker from state.items is displayed on the map, although I have more coordinates in the table. Please help

```
state={
items:[{
      "X": 13.6155611,
      "Y": 51.0331258
    },
    ],
}

 addItem = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const newItem = {
      "Y": parseFloat(this.state.X),
      "X": parseFloat(this.state.Y),
    };
    this.setState(prevState => ({
      items: [...prevState.items, newItem]
    }));

  }
componentDidMount() {
    const map = new mapboxgl.Map({
      container: this.mapContainer,
      center: [this.state.lng, this.state.lat],
      zoom: this.state.zoom,
    });

}

 render() {
for (var i = 0; i < this.state.items.length; i++) {
      var obj = this.state.items[i];
      let myLatlng = new mapboxgl.LngLat(obj.X, obj.Y);
      new mapboxgl.Marker()
        .setLngLat(myLatlng)
        .addTo(this.map);
    }
    return (
        <div ref={el => this.mapContainer = el} />

<form onSubmit={this.addItem}>
 <input
              type="number"
              value={this.state.X}
              onChange={e => this.setState({
                X: e.target.value
              })}
            />
            <input
              value={this.state.Y}
              onChange={e => this.setState({
                Y: e.target.value
              })}
            />
</Form>
)}
```

Comment: `this.map` is working? since `map` is defined as const inside componentDidMount

Comment: does not work .. without this = 'map' is not defined..

Comment: Yeah agreed, that only `map` would not be defined, as its scope is only inside `componentDidMount `. Try adding `this.map = new mapboxgl.Map(()=>{}) `instead of `const map = `

Comment: Can it be fixed differently? because Other functions don't work for me