# how to call function ? ComponentDidMount does not match here

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How to call addMap functions in render? 
ComponentDidMount does not match here

```
 addMap = () => {
    const map = new mapboxgl.Map({
      container: this.mapContainer,
      zoom: this.state.zoom,
    })
}

 render() {
    return (

)}
```

Comment: [`useEffect()`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html) hook may do

Comment: why does `ComponentDidMount` not match here ? If you are using `render` then you are using `Class` components and so you can use the `ComponentDidMount` method.

Comment: here I described the problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61349288/adding-markers-to-the-map